# Plot python pandas pivot_table with errorbars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I have CSV data representing a set of experimental samples. I have been using the pandas pivot_table functionality to summarize this data (hmean). I can plot this data easily with pyplot.

I would like to add errorbars in terms of the standard deviation to this plot. I can add a std computation to the pivot_table but I can't figure out how to get that plotted.

Example data:

```
Version,Cores,Rate
B, 24, 17284.202851
B, 24, 16978.950593
B, 24, 17420.640853
B, 24, 18459.647352
B, 24, 18432.847955
A, 24, 8718.459497
A, 24, 8709.560992
A, 24, 8712.219874
A, 24, 8697.659670
A, 24, 8687.926290
B, 48, 21478.308781
B, 48, 21478.500370
B, 48, 21459.274459
B, 48, 21479.346576
B, 48, 21443.547086
A, 48, 17706.794211
A, 48, 17840.683281
A, 48, 17728.789484
A, 48, 17677.580304
A, 48, 17834.253133
```

Pivoting:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sp

# read in the data                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
samples=pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)

aggfunc=[sp.hmean]

summary=pd.pivot_table(samples, index='Cores', values='Rate',
                       columns=['Version'],
                       aggfunc=aggfunc)

print(summary)
```

Plotting:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax=summary.plot(logx=True, grid=True, style='o-',  fontsize=10)
ax.set_xticks(summary.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(summary.index)
plt.savefig("fig.pdf")
```

It would be nice if I could get this to be a scatter plot too, but for now just getting error bars would be enough.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and it doesn't appear that pandas supports plotting error bars directly from a pivottable. But, you can achieve the result you want using `groupby`:

```
means = samples.groupby('Cores').means()
errors = samples.groupby('Cores').errors()

means.plot.bar(yerr=errors)
```

This works for me with a similar set of experimental results that I want grouped by category. The above is very similar to the example given in the pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-error-bars). You may have to modify in order to make use of `hmean()` instead of `mean()`.